# Intercept DNS request in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, google-chrome-extension

If I want to test http://www.domain.com, but I want to test two versions of it by switching the IP out (e.g. one resolves to 127.0.0.1 and the other 192.168.1.200) is it possible to write/use a chrome extension to handle intercepting the DNS query and resolving to my IP of choice?

The current workaround is to utilize the hosts file and flush the DNS cache to switch between them but that's less than optimal and was hoping a browser extension could handle the same thing.

Comment: Not really Chrome-specific, but the debugging proxy Fiddler has this functionality (and more): http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hosts.asp (alas, Windows-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mechanism to manipulate DNS requests/responses natively inside Chrome, not even via the upcoming WebRequest API.

Is there a reason that you need to test with exactly the same domain name? Setting up a dev environment on something like http://dev.example.com/ (or http://example.dev/ if you run your own DNS or have edited your hosts file) is a clean mechanism for producing the effect you want in a way that's functional with the APIs you have access to; writing an extension that gave you a button to toggle between the two domains with the push of a button would be trivial

Comment: That was going to be my first approach, but in porting one production server with 100+ web apps to another production server containing things like WordPress could prove to be a little more difficult as WordPress keeps URL/domain information hard coded in various places.  If I can keep the Apache vhost configurations identical, it'll prevent having to temporarily re-configure 100+ apps with hard-coded URLs and then revert back during the switch.

Comment: In that case, you're out of luck.  :)  I'd suggest running with Piskvor's suggestion, using a proxy to fake the resolution.  Fiddler works well on Windows, Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) works well everywhere.

Comment: Didn't know about Charles, looks awesome.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I'm running a Virtualbox Windows XP machine just to have Fiddler (it can work as a normal HTTP proxy too), but you're right, not everybody has a spare Windows license lying around.

Comment: I was also looking for this kind of extension but after reading your answer, I just realized that how worse it could be if this is permitted by any browser. Like if extension maker do something with you DNS settings and the domain like paypal.com or your bank's domain will start pointing to any other custom server/IP and they could get your passwords etc very easily. And in result, you could be robbed very easily... :D :D

Comment: "" writing an extension that gave you a button to toggle between the two domains with the push of a button would be trivial "" -- Trivial to who?